# Retaining just unique elements in a queue

Tags: c++, vector

I have queue of vectors of the following form:

```
queue<vector<unsigned> > a;
vector<unsigned> b;
b.push_back(10); b.push_back(12); b.push_back(15);
a.push(b);
vector<unsigned> b2;
b1.push_back(15); b1.push_back(19); b1.push_back(18);
vector<unsigned> b1;
b1.push_back(10); b1.push_back(12); b1.push_back(15);
```

I want to enter only unique vectors in the queue. For example in the example above I want to retain just the vector elements: (10,12,15),(15,19,18) i.e here I have removed the duplicate element: (10,12,15) and have retained its copy just once.

One of the ways of checking whether a vector is already present in the queue or not is to iterate over it. Is there some other way by which I can check whether a vector is already present in the queue or not efficiently?

I am using gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: Are your vectors all of three elements?

Comment: @Mat: Yes vectors all of three elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of insertion is important, then I would use a second data structure to keep track of the unique inserted elements, such as `std::set`.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class unique_queue {
private:
    std::queue<T> m_queue;
    std::set<T> m_set;
public:
    bool push(const T& t) {
        if (m_set.insert(t).second) {
            m_queue.push(t);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void pop() {
        assert(!m_queue.empty());
        const T& val = front();

        typename std::set<T>::iterator it = m_set.find(val);
        assert(it != m_set.end());

        m_set.erase(it);
        m_queue.pop();
    }

    const T& front() const {
        return m_queue.front();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unique_queue<std::vector<unsigned> > q;

    std::vector<unsigned> b1;
    b1.push_back(10); b1.push_back(12); b1.push_back(15);
    std::cout << "pushed: " << q.push(b1) << std::endl;

    std::vector<unsigned> b2;
    b2.push_back(15); b2.push_back(17); b2.push_back(18);
    std::cout << "pushed: " << q.push(b2) << std::endl;

    std::vector<unsigned> b3;
    b3.push_back(10); b3.push_back(12); b3.push_back(15);
    std::cout << "pushed: " << q.push(b3) << std::endl;

    q.pop();
    q.pop();
    std::cout << "pushed: " << q.push(b3) << std::endl;
}
```

By default, `std::set<T>` will use `std::less<T>` to compare its elements. For a `std::vector<unsigned>`, this boils down to lexicographically comparing the vectors when inserting them into the set.

Comment: How can can retrieve and pop out the topmost element from this queue?

Comment: I tried to call vector<unsigned> temp=q.back(); but it gives me all the elements which were inserted in the queue till now

Comment: Yes, I was using the wrong vectors for the second insert (b1 instead of b2). That's fixed now. I'm going to add a method to pop the oldest vector in a minute.

Comment: If you go with this idea, also take note of @Ulrich's comments in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Queues are not the data structures that give you efficient search by the element values (they are essentially like vectors).  Sets are, but they do not guarantee the ordering of elements.

Use [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) that will try to give the best solution with respect to the actual queue organization.

Comment: [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) does guarantee ordering of elements. (Perhaps you are thinking of [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)?)

Comment: It does guarantee that they are sorted while the queue stores them in the order of addition.  These two are not the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. I was only contending your statement "Sets ... do not guarantee the ordering of elements."

Answer (score 1):

If you have such special requirements, I tend to not use the standard containers directly. Instead, I define an interface first:

```
class my_queue {
public:
    typedef vector<unsigned> element_type;
    void push(element_type const&);
    bool empty() const;
    element_type pop();
```

Then, since you want elements to be unique, I'd use a regular queue and a set:

```
private:
    queue<element_type> m_queue;
    set<element_type> m_set;
};
```

I think you get the point and I'm too lazy to fire up a compiler to actually test this. ;)

Some further notes:

- Even though it's more complex, a vector is just a datatype, so it can be assigned, copied and compared. This comparison is used by e.g. `std::set`.
- This could be optimized, since the storage of the data in both is actually redundant. I'd then store the actual elements in the set and their order in the queue (i.e. store set iterators).
- Unless you store many elements in the queue, doing a linear search over the queue (using e.g. std::deque as replacement) might be a better-performing alternative.
- It's not clear whether inserting a duplicate should influence the order. Also, what if elements were already removed and then added back? In any case, write tests that make sure the queue has the required behaviour.